# How to add image as background of block

Tags: css, background

Can someone help me to understand what am i doing wrong? Want to add an image at the top center but it doesn't show anything. Here is a css code.Thank you.

```
div.header {
    background: url(photo/header.png) no-repeat ;
    display: block;
    width: 1002px;
    height:178px;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. That should work. Any errors in the console? http://output.jsbin.com/gibewipebo

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you even read the comments man?

Comment: Yes, I've just checked it and it says Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND          but photo is in that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the path of the image like `(../photo/header.png)`
can u make a folder stucture?. is the html file and photo folder in same folder?

Comment: No html is in the kgproject folder and i just changed the path to (kgproject/photo/header.png) didn't work.

Comment: no thats wrong. try copying photo folder in same folder as your html file.

Comment: u should create a folder structure that shows where the html file is save and where the photo folder is save. in your code both html file and photo folder must be at the same folder. but in ur cases their in different folders right?.

Comment: In kgproject I have html file and folder containing images, named folder. So they are in the same folder.

Comment: Now i seeee))) I put image to html file folder and it worked)) Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: so the folder name of where the header.png is folder?. am i right? if that so then try `(../folder/header.png)`

Comment: Glad i can help, but u need to learn more about creating path. i now its complicated at first. but you will get it. =)

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more information about the problem. There is maybe a typo in your code. If you use the background or background-image property, you have to use quotation marks. Like this: background: url('photo/header.png') no-repeat;

Comment: I have already tried that and even with background-image but none of this changes worked. If this code is fine then it must be something wrong with files or directories. Thank you very much for help.